gmp_mod Argument #1 ($num1) is not an integer string Hashids package
I'm using the latest version of Hashids in my Laravel 11 project running PHP 8.3 and have stumbled upon an issue, given the following, which is a numeric string:
(new Hashids('', 7))->encode('09009956789098')

An error is produced:

gmp_mod(): Argument #1 ($num1) is not an integer string

I have GMP installed via PHP on the server. What are the workarounds for this please?

A numeric string starting with 0 is interpreted as octal. 8 and 9 are not valid octal digits.
